# Huge icons in Powerpoint

Tags: resolution, microsoft-powerpoint, touchscreen

I have a new laptop with a pretty nice touch screen with a resolution of 2560 x 1440px.

In Powerpoint (it's version 2016) all the icons are super huge such that I can't even see the entire menu.

Any idea why that is so and how to reduce the icon size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out on my own:

The icon size is not related to the resolution but to the fact that it's a touch screen.

The distance between icons is increased for touch screens. There is this icon in the top menu bar where you can change this:

[image]